# Slack events adaptor not giving a proper response

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api

I was trying to make a slack bot using slackeventsapi running on ngrok for now.

It can send messages properly but slack events adaptor doesn't seem to be working properly. It gives the code 200 every time a message is sent but the payload doesn't come. I tried printing it but the printing it shows nothing.

There was another post asking a similar question whose solution in the end was to make a new app on slack API but it doesn't seem to fix my issue. I have made another app but the issue persists.

I was following a tutorial so I have tried to match his code exactly but it doesn't seem to work even then. In case it will be helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gHvqXrfjuo&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kqyzTzJWCV6lyK-ZMYECDc&index=2.

[The slack API scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiHlq.png)
[Slack API Subscriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLCiO.png)

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

env_path = Path('.')/'.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['TEST2_SLACK_TOKEN'])
BOT_ID = client.api_call("auth.test")['user_id']

app = Flask(__name__)
slack_event_adaptor = SlackEventAdapter(os.environ['SIGNING_SECRET2'], '/slack/events', app)

client.chat_postMessage(channel=f'#new', text="Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

@slack_event_adaptor.on('message')
def message(payload):
    print(payload)
    event = payload.get('event',{})
    channel_id = event.get('channel')
    user_id = event.get('user')
    text = event.get('text')

    if BOT_ID != user_id:
        client.chat_postMessage(channel= channel_id, text = text)
```

Comment: Did you enabled event on Event Subscriptions tab?

Comment: Yep. I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem when I used slack_event_adaptor and then I tried slack_bolt and everything works well. Let me share example you may try if you want:

```
import re

from config import config
from flask import Flask, request
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

slack_token = config.slack_token
client = WebClient(slack_token)
bolt_app = App(token=slack_token, signing_secret=config.signing_secret)
handler = SlackRequestHandler(bolt_app)

@bolt_app.message(re.compile("Hello bot",re.IGNORECASE))
def reply_in_thread(payload: dict):
    """ This will reply in thread instead of creating a new thread """
    response = client.chat_postMessage(channel=payload.get('channel'),
                                     thread_ts=payload.get('ts'),
                                     text=f"Hello<@{payload['user']}>")

@app.route("/datalake/events", methods=["POST"])
def slack_events():
    """ Declaring the route where slack will post a request """
    return handler.handle(request)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

When you write "Hello bot" bot will respond you accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response :D. I was trying to use this but when I try to put ngroksessionID\slack\events in event subscriptions, it keeps returning error 404... I'm sorry. I'm new to this so I'm probably messing it up somewhere. I put in the auth token and signing secret from my API app and just tried the same process as I had done for the above code. Run the python file, go to ngrok, write ngrok.exe HTTP 5000, then pasted the URL\slack\events into event subscriptions

Comment: Route is /datalake/events there if you copy pasted above one, I see no other reason if you already specified http 5000 while executing ngrok instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It finally responds :D. Just to confirm, this is the documentation for bolt right? - https://slack.dev/bolt-python/tutorial/getting-started

Comment: Yes, and also check repo for a lot of examples. https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python. If it helped please upvote and accept my answer. I will be appreciated :) Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks A LOT for the help :D. I'm new to Stackoverflow so I can't upvote it but I accepted the answer.